# Importing data from one Neo4j server to another

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j and looking for the right way to export and import data from one neo4j server to another. Based on the reading I've not come across a standard way of doing this. Any thoughts/inputs on how to go about this?

Comment: Do you want to copy the entire graph or just a subgraph?

Comment: Primarily looking at importing the entire graph. For importing a subgraph, I have come across some ideas. One of them bing using the neo4j browser to export the data and then using neo4j shell to import it.

Answer (score 0):

To copy an entire Neo4j database from one instance to another, simply stop Neo4j, copy the `graph.db` directory to the other Neo4j instance and start that Neo4j instance.

Similar to the steps explained [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_backup_restore.htm).

Comment: Ok, this option is not feasible for me at this point, because I do not have access to login to the remote server to copy/download the file.